# Handlebars #if and numeric zeroes

Tags: handlebars.js

In my Handlebars template I check for the existence of a variable, and render some text if it's there:

```
{{#if foo}}
  some text
{{/if}}
```

This works fine if foo is text or if foo is numeric but not zero. But if

```
var foo = 0;
```

then `{{#if foo}}` returns false.

This appears to be yet another Javascript oddity, because Javascript itself behaves the same way. In Javascript code, though, you could get around this by checking if the variable is 'undefined'.

How can I do the same thing in Handlebars?

I could write an `{{#exists}}` helper, but I was hoping there was something built in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would go one better and provide a case for the {{else}} condition...

```
/**
 * The {{#exists}} helper checks if a variable is defined.
 */
Handlebars.registerHelper('exists', function(variable, options) {
    if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Now you can have:

```
{{#exists myvar}}
  <p>Value of myvar is ... {{myvar}}</p>
{{else}}
  <p>Please supply a myvar</p>
{{/exists}}
```

Answer (score 36):

There is something built in for this:

```
{{#if foo includeZero=true}}
    foo!
{{/if}}
```

This displays `foo!` when `foo` is `0`.

Comment: This feature was added in october: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/608 , but good to point this out for future visitors.

Comment: @JustusRomijn Thats why I added it.

Answer (score 1):

I just went ahead and wrote an {{#exists}} helper. But if someone has a better solution, please post it.

```
/**
 * The {{#exists}} helper checks if a variable is defined.
 */
Handlebars.registerHelper('exists', function(variable, options) {
    if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this error "Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'SEP'" using @Shane method make sure you have no spaces in:

```
{{ /exist }}
```

And change it to this:

```
{{/exist}}
```