# Check existence of a variable in handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've a javascript object like :

```
var data = {
"current" : 0,
"max" : 5,
"reward" : 5
};
```

And  I'm crating a HTML with this data using handlebar like :

```
<div>
<span>Current : {{current}}</span>
<span>Max : {{max}}</span>
<span>Reward: {{reward}}</span>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, the reward property may not be always present in the data, and in that case I don't want to show that span. So, I made the following:-

```
{{#if reward}}
 <span>Reward: {{reward}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

And it's working, if the reward property is not present, it's not showing the span, but it's also not showing the span if the value of reward is 0, can anybody suggest how to solve it. I can use some helper function. But, can I do that without using any helper function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handlebars #if and numeric zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095813/handlebars-if-and-numeric-zeroes)

Comment: In your `data` object, you could have a `rewardExists` boolean and then in your template: `{{#if rewardExists}}`.

Comment: Actually I can solve this by some helper function or by adding an extra variable, I just want to know if there is any such tag that handlebar provides. "if" is not working here, anything else?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is by design `if` checks for `falsy` values see [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com)

> You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its
>   argument returns false, undefined, null, "" or [] (a "falsy" value),
>   Handlebars will not render the block.

there's a `includeZero` option use like:

```
{{#if reward includeZero=true}}
{{/if}}
```

You can see the implementation of the helper here: [on github](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/148b19182d70278237a62d8293db540483a0c46c/lib/handlebars/helpers/if.js#L3-L20)

Comment: If I overwrite the actual if helper, it'll be applied in the other templates also. So if in any other template, I add/remove any block depending on a value of a variable including 0, it'll not work. I can't change the default if helper for a single template.

Anyways the link was helpful, I understand I need to write a custom helper.

Comment: doesn't seem like this works with empty arrays unfortunately

Comment: @stackers use `array.length`

Answer (score 0):

instead of #if you should use `#unless`: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#unless